# Jest relative imports can't find node_modules

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to migrate an old node project with a heap of tech debt to modern practices.  I'm hoping to do so without changing the existing code base so we can evaluate both build systems.  Currently running into a problem getting jest to resolve relative sibling dependencies:

```
../common/lib/thing.ts
../disp/
../disp/node_modules
../disp/Component/Component.tsx
```

Component.tsx depends on `thing.ts`:
`import { thing } from 'common/thing'

If `thing.ts` imports from `node_modules` it will fail to find the import.

**If I symlink the disp/node_modules to common/node_modules it will build fine.**

It seems to only be able to look upward regardless of how I define `jest.config.js`.  I've tried numerous combinations of the module resolution settings, it seems jest will only ever look up.

`disp/jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // rootDir: './',
  // roots: ["."],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest.setup.ts"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  testMatch: ["**/*.test.(ts|tsx)"],
  // modulePaths: ["node_modules"],
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "<rootDir>/node_modules"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ...pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
    // "^int64-buffer/(.*)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/int64-buffer/$1",
    "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "identity-obj-proxy",
    "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
};
```

Error:

```
Cannot find module 'int64-buffer' or its corresponding type declarations.

    27 import { Uint64BE } from 'int64-buffer';
```

Comment: hey did you find any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is how Jest works, it only resolves UP using dirname()

see
https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c44de55e585be824092465ed7a21d0a59c11c2ee/packages/jest-resolve/src/defaultResolver.ts#L135

and

https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/c44de55e585be824092465ed7a21d0a59c11c2ee/packages/jest-resolve/src/fileWalkers.ts#L93

```
export function findClosestPackageJson(start: string): string | undefined {
  let dir = resolve('.', start);
  if (!isDirectory(dir)) {
    dir = dirname(dir);
  }

  while (true) {
    const pkgJsonFile = resolve(dir, './package.json');
    const hasPackageJson = isFile(pkgJsonFile);

    if (hasPackageJson) {
      return pkgJsonFile;
    }

    const prevDir = dir;
    dir = dirname(dir);

    if (prevDir === dir) {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
}
```